# Delete a file from Box api v2 with Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest, box

Currently struggling to delete a file from Box in Node.js. I'm using the request module. [The docs state](https://box-content.readme.io/#delete-a-file) that to delete a file, you must use the "delete" method. However, I'm getting a status 405 "method not allowed. I've already validated that req.body.id contains the correct information. Here's my code:

```
    request({method:"DELETE",url:"https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/"+req.body.id.id,
      headers:{
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.session.box_access_token,
        'If-Match':req.body.id.etag
      }
    },function(err, response, body) {
      next();
    });
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Is it supposed to be `req.body.id.id`?  Or should it be `req.body.id`?

Answer (score 0):

And I'm an idiot. Url should be: "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/". I had https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/".